# How to write SQL query to find the total bonus amount they should receive given that the bonus gets calculated only for referrals_valid=1

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT P.profile_id
       , (P.first_name+' '+P.last_name) AS [Full Name]
       , P.email
       , P.phone
       , P.referral_code
       , R.[Total referrals]
       , R.[Total Bonus Amount] 
FROM Profiles P 
JOIN (SELECT referrer_id
             , SUM(referrer_bonus_amount) AS [Total Bonus Amount]
             , COUNT(referrer_id) AS [Total referrals] 
      FROM Referrals
      GROUP BY referrer_id) R 
ON P.profile_id=R.referrer_id 
WHERE R.[Total referrals] > 1
```

Above is the code for which I am getting the results as below
[Query results image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6pOq8.png) but now I need to calculate the Total Bonus Amount only for valid_referrals column equal to 1
(Note: valid_referrals column comes from Referrals table.)

Can someone help me out with the code....??

Comment: Add some sample data and expected result data. Also when you will add that do add it as a text not as a image. Alongside that, a table definitions would be great...

Comment: (This doesn't look like MySQL)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `case when` :

```
SELECT P.profile_id
       , (P.first_name+' '+P.last_name) AS [Full Name]
       , P.email
       , P.phone
       , P.referral_code
       , R.[Total referrals]
       , R.[Total Bonus Amount] 
       , R.[Total Valid Bonus Amount] 
FROM Profiles P 
JOIN (SELECT R1.referrer_id
             , SUM(R1.referrer_bonus_amount) AS [Total Bonus Amount]
             , SUM(case when valid_referrals = 1 then R1.referrer_bonus_amount
                    else 0
               end) AS [Total Valid Bonus Amount]
             , COUNT(referrer_id) AS [Total referrals] 
      FROM Referrals R1
      GROUP BY referrer_id) R 
ON P.profile_id=R.referrer_id 
WHERE R.[Total referrals] > 1
```

With subquery:

```
SELECT P.profile_id
       , (P.first_name+' '+P.last_name) AS [Full Name]
       , P.email
       , P.phone
       , P.referral_code
       , R.[Total referrals]
       , R.[Total Bonus Amount] 
       , R.[Total Valid Bonus Amount] 
FROM Profiles P 
JOIN (SELECT R1.referrer_id
             , SUM(R1.referrer_bonus_amount) AS [Total Bonus Amount]
             , (select sum(R2.referrer_bonus_amount) 
                from Referrals R2 
                where R1.referrer_id = R2.referrer_id
                and valid_referrals = 1) AS [Total Valid Bonus Amount]
             , COUNT(referrer_id) AS [Total referrals] 
      FROM Referrals R1
      GROUP BY referrer_id) R 
ON P.profile_id=R.referrer_id 
WHERE R.[Total referrals] > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

it seems that by adding the where clause in your subquery, it should do the job.

```
SELECT P.profile_id, 
  (P.first_name+' '+P.last_name) AS [Full Name], 
  P.email, 
  P.phone, 
  P.referral_code, 
  R.[Total referrals], 
  R.[Total Bonus Amount] 
FROM Profiles P 
JOIN (
  SELECT 
   referrer_id,SUM(referrer_bonus_amount) AS [Total Bonus Amount], 
   COUNT(referrer_id) AS [Total referrals] 
  FROM Referrals
  WHERE Referrals.referral_valid = 1
  GROUP BY referrer_id
) R 
ON P.profile_id=R.referrer_id  
WHERE R.[Total referrals]>1
```

Comment: Thanks @Benjamin, my motto here was to get all the results where Total referrals >1 and at the same time calculate sum only for referral_valid=1 and the code which VBoka shared below had resolved my issue... Thanks for your help